# remove query string from url through mod rewrite

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am very new to mod rewrite so any help would be apprecited.

let say i  have a site named "www.sitename.com/index.php?p=contact"
and i need to remove  "index.php?p="
so that it will look like "www.sitename/contact"
at its every occurence that means either i should be able to truncate "index.php?p=" or i should be able to replace it with some word.

Comment: `smarty` tag, as well as `php`, has nothing to do with this question. also you could add `mod-rewrite` tag

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule (.*) index.php?p=$1
```

Answer (score 0):

@zerkms 
Your answer doesn't work, it's not complete

There should be

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/[^.]+$
RewriteRule (.*) index.php?p=$1
```

These lines matches URI with no extension, so .php and .html files 
will still be available